# Do mysql setting Spanish equal English？

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I run this command

```
select 'Conceição do Almeida'='Conceicao do Almeida';
```

The left side of the equal sign is Spanish,and the other side is English.

But,It return 1 as result!

Obviously, this is completely different two strings!

Do mysql setting  Spanish equal English？

By the way

```
character_set_client        utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database      utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       utf8mb4
character_set_server        utf8
character_set_system        utf8
```

So I don't think this about coding errors.

Comment: The compare depends on the collation you use.

Comment: Nitpick: it's not "English", it's simply non-accented characters, a.k.a. "plain ASCII".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compare depends on the collation you use.

See [this SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/50619).

So either change your table collation or use a specific collation in your queries like `utf8_bin`.

Comment: Collation or type of the string (normal or binary). In case of binary string the comparison is done on a byte basis, not character basis, as if a binary collation were used. You can even force a comparison to use binary string with the binary operator: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-binary-op.html